# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X f_n d\mu=2023$ and measures

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, measurable-functions

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $\{f_n\}_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{M}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}}^+(\mathcal{A})$. Assume that $f_n\to f$ for $n\to \infty$ and that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X f_n d\mu=2023$$

Argue that $f\in\mathcal{M}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}}^+(\mathcal{A})$ and that $\int_X f d\mu\leq 2023$. Argue that if $f_1\leq f_2\leq\ldots.$ then $\int_X f d\mu=2023$

---

$\mathcal{M}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}}^+(\mathcal{A})$ is for the families of (extended) real-valued positive measurable functions.

I am thinking that since the sequence is in $\mathcal{M}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}}^+(\mathcal{A})$ and $f_n\to f$ for $n\to\infty $ then $f(=\sup f_n?)$ must also be in $\mathcal{M}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}}^+(\mathcal{A})$.
I have been using this theorem but unsure on how to apply it exactly:

---

**Theorem**: Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space. If $u_n : X \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, are measurable functions, then so are
$$
\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} u_n, \quad \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} u_n, \quad \limsup_{n \to \infty} u_n, \quad \text{and} \quad \liminf_{n \to \infty} u_n,
$$
and, whenever it exists in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n$.

---

For the two other claims regarding the integral I am not sure whatsoever. It seems awful lot like a set up for Beppo Levi but I have not applied the theorem before so I am unsure on both the approach and if I am allowed to.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you know the [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma)?

Comment: @Feng what do you suggest to be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The hypothesis that $f_n\to f$ as $n\to\infty $ does NOT imply $f=\sup f_n$. Indeed, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n=f=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n$, and thus $f$ is measurable and non-negative provided that $f_n\in\mathcal{M}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}}^+(\mathcal{A})$ for each $n\in\mathbb N_{\geq1}$.
- By [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma), we have
  $$\int_X \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n\,d\mu\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_X f_n\,d\mu.$$
  Combining the above with $f=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_X f_n d\mu=2023$ gives that $\int_Xf\,d\mu\leq 2023$.
- If $\{f_n\}_{n\geq1}$ is moreover a non-decreasing sequence, then [Beppo Levi's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi%27s_lemma) implies that
  $$\int_X f\,d\mu =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_X f_n d\mu=2023.$$

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have one small issue. How are we using the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_X f_n d\mu=2023$? As of now I am unsure on how the RHS when using Fatou's would help us?

Comment: Please let me know if I should elaborate my question.

Comment: @learningsolo Let $a_n=\int_Xf_n\,d\mu$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=2023$. For a convergence sequence of real numbers, the lower limit equals to the limit, so $\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n=2023$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @learningsolo  Yes. That’s correct.

Comment: The more you know thank you. For the part using Beppo Levi; Say we were to just say that $f_n\leq f$ for all $n\geq 1$ instead of the increasing sequence. Could I show that the integral is again equal to 2023 just by now finding a lower bound of the integral

Comment: *(as in the sequence is not necessarily increasing)*

Comment: @learningsolo  Good point! You can do that.

Comment: Sorry for taking up your time but I am actually learning a lot from this!

Comment: @learningsolo You’re welcome. However, I won’t take the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf\,d\mu$ if I’m writing a proof, because $\int f$ is a specific number which doesn’t rely on $n$. The idea in my mind is to use the property that if $a_n\leq a$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq a$. Nevertheless, your proof is OK, too.

Comment: I see, so remove the limit on the RHS of line two then the proof is fine? What would the argument be for the the implication $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq a$ from $a_n\leq a$?

Comment: @learningsolo Yes. As you say, just remove the limit on the RHS is fine. Your proof is just OK. Different person has different taste on proofs.

Comment: As long as it is correct I think its fine. May I ask why $a_n\leq a \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq a$

Comment: @learningsolo This is a basic property on limits. Denote $A=\lim a_n$. If $A>a$, then take $\epsilon=(A-a)/2$ in the definition of the limit, and then you will get a contradiction …